# PExec doesn't exit after execute

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file

I'm writing a program with C# , that can create Users on remote Computers.
Actually it's done and working.
But I have one little problem.

In C# I use PowerShell to run a Script which runs then an Pexec, which executes a Batch file on a remote Computer.

C# :

```
private void executeScripts()
    {
        string _dirPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        string _sPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_dirPath) + @"\ExecuteScripts\FileToExecute.ps1";
        string _scriptPath = "& '" + _sPath + "'";

        using (PowerShellProcessInstance pspi = new PowerShellProcessInstance())
        {
            string psfn = pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName;
            psfn = psfn.ToLowerInvariant().Replace("\\syswow64\\", "\\sysnative\\");
            pspi.Process.StartInfo.FileName = psfn;

            using (Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null, pspi))
            {
                r.Open();
                using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                {
                    ps.Runspace = r;
                    ps.AddScript(_scriptPath);
                    ps.Invoke();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

PS Script :

```
#
# First there are some Copy-Items to the remote Computer
#

# Execute Above copied Bat File on remote Computer
[string] $IPAddress = "\\" + $XmlFile.ComputerSettings.LastChild.ChildNodes[1].InnerText
$PsTools = "\PsTools"
$PsToolsPath = Join-Path -path $ScriptParent -childpath $PsTools
& $PsToolsPath\PsExec.exe $IPAddress /accepteula -i -s -u $Login -p $LoginPassword Powershell  C:\Path\ToBatFile\Execute.bat > log.txt

Exit
```

I use this PExec 3 other times in my Program, creating a User, updating a User and removing a User, i just execute different files, scripts or batch files.
And it works perfectly.

But with the Script above, the PExec executes everything but doesn't exit. Neiter does it log something.
I tried it also with the -d switch, but that didn't work either. I also put an exit /b in the batch file but no luck.

When running the script manually from Powershell it works, it executes and it exits, but when running it from my Program it doesn't.

After some waiting my C# returns a timed-out Exception end exits.

Anyone seeing what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You’re using the /I switch which is for interactive. Remove that

Comment: So why aren't you using WinRM for PowerShell to begin with? `Invoke-Command -ComputerName <hostname> -Command {<script>}`

Answer (score 1):

Powershell class itself has a method called `Stop()` which makes it pretty easy to stop this.

If you want to do it asynchronously here is an example of implementation:

```
using(cancellationToken.Register(() => powershell.Stop())
{
    await Task.Run(() => powershell.Invoke(powershellCommand), cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: thx for that answer, i searched for something like that :)